# How can i use onActivityResult the way i want

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmap, onactivityresult

I´m learning android/java by myself @the moment and i have a problem with a part of my app i´m learning on.

I made the code with help of the www and my problem is that if i open an image from the gallery it´s send to the edit activity but the quality of the picture is really bad.

Code with the main problem i think:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY:
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got Picture!");
                        Log.d(TAG,"File type - " + data.getType());
                        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
                        if (photoUri != null)
                        {
                            try {
                                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                                String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
                                int orientation = -1;
                                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                                cursor.close();
                                cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
                                if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                                    orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
                                }
                                cursor.close();

                                HashMap<String, Integer> pRes = this.getImageResolutionSetting();
                                Bitmap shrunkenBitmap = FileUtilsHelper.shrinkBitmap(filePath, pRes.get("width"), pRes.get("height"));
                                shrunkenBitmap = rotateBitmapToOrientation(shrunkenBitmap, orientation);
                                String res = FileUtilsHelper.saveBitmapAsJpeg(shrunkenBitmap, this);
                                Log.d(TAG,"File Path: " + res);
                                shrunkenBitmap.recycle();
                                Intent editImage = new Intent(this, EditImage.class);
                                editImage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
                                editImage.putExtra("stuff.path", res);

                                startActivity(editImage);
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.cant_save_image,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        }

                }
            }
            break;
            }
}}
```

I want now to rewrite the complete onActivityResult so it´s using 1:1 the picture from the gallery or remove the parts:
shrinkBitmap (i think thats the main problem of the bad quality)
rotateBitmapToOrientation (because it´s always false orientated)

But i don´t know how that is working...

If i´m deleting that parts it´s not working anymore i could really need a teacher on that :)

Thx for your help dudes!!

Comment: As I understand, in `filePath` you have the file path. So if you pass it (via putExtra()) instead of `res`, you will edit the original image.

Comment: How does that work do i have to change res to filePath?
I tried that but it is the same.
Thank you! @18446744073709551615

Comment: I mean it´s working i can delete that parts but the quality is the same(bad)
Do you have an idea what my problem is?
Should i post my FileUtilsHelper Class?
Thx for your help.
@18446744073709551615

Comment: Post your comment as answer i mark it as right because i could remove the parts i asked for.
The bad quality problem is something else `public HashMap<String,Integer> getImageResolutionSetting` is the main problem.maybe i´m opening a new question for that.
thx for your help!
@18446744073709551615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In filePath you have the file path. So if you pass it (via putExtra()) instead of res, you will edit the original image.